# Order of convergence of false position method is the golden ratio.

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, nonlinear-optimization, fibonacci-numbers, regula-falsi

I'm reading about the order of convergence of the method of false position and there is one tricky point in the proof I don't understand. The method itself for finding the minimum $x^*$ of a function $f(x)$ is:

$$x_{k+1} = x_k-g(x_k)\left[ \frac{x_k-x_{k-1}}{g(x_k)-g(x_{k-1})} \right],$$

where $g(x) := f'(x)$. The proposition is the following:

> **Proposition:**
>
> Let $g$ have a continuous second derivative and suppose $x^*$ is such
>    that $g(x^*)=0, g'(x^*)\neq 0$. Then for $x_0$ sufficiently close to
>    $x^*$, the sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ generated by the method
>    of false position above converges to $x^*$ with order $\tau_1 \simeq
> 1.618$, which is the golden mean.

In the following I have written the proof from the part I start having troubles:

> Defining $\epsilon = x_k-x^*$ we have, in the limit ($k\rightarrow
>  \infty$),
>
> $$\epsilon_{k+1} = M\epsilon_{k}\epsilon_{k-1},\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
>
> where $\displaystyle M=\frac{g''(x^*)}{2g'(x^*)}$. Taking logarithm of both sides of
>   $(1)$, we have with $y_k = \log M\epsilon_{k}$,
>
> $$y_{k+1} = y_k + y_{k-1},\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$
>
> which is the Fibonacci difference equation. A solution to this
>   equation will satisfy
>
> $$y_{k+1}-\tau_1y_k \rightarrow 0.\;\;\;\;\;\;(3)$$
>
> Thus
>
> $$\log M\epsilon_{k+1}-\tau_1\log M\epsilon_{k}\rightarrow 0$$
>
> or
>
> $$\log \frac{M\epsilon_{k+1}}{(M\epsilon_k)^{\tau_1}} \rightarrow 0,$$
>
> and hence
>
> $$\frac{\epsilon_{k+1}}{\epsilon_{k}^{\tau_1}} \rightarrow M^{\tau_1
>  -1 }. \blacksquare$$

This is taken from: [Linear and Nonlinear programming, 3rd edition](http://grapr.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/luenberger-linear-and-nonlinear-programming-3e-springer-2008.pdf) by David Luenberger, page 224.

**My questions:**

1. How did $(2)$ follow from $(1)$?
2. Explanation for $(3)$?

**My try:**

If I take the logarithm of $(1)$ myself I get:

$$\log \epsilon_{k+1}=\log M\epsilon_k + \log\epsilon_{k-1},$$

so what am I doing wrong here?...

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This is for part A. Multiply the equation with $M$:
$$\epsilon_{k+1} = M\epsilon_{k}\epsilon_{k-1}\\
\Longrightarrow M \epsilon_{k+1} = (M\epsilon_{k})(M\epsilon_{k-1})\\
\Longrightarrow \log(M \epsilon_{k+1}) = \log(M\epsilon_{k})+\log(M\epsilon_{k-1})\\
\Longrightarrow y_{k+1} = y_{k}+y_{k-1}
$$

Comment: For the connection between the Fibonacci relation (3) and the golden ratio $\tau_1$ or $\varphi$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence).  Assuming $y_{k+1} = y_k + y_{k-1}$ has a geometric solution $y_k = a R^k$ leads to the quadratic $R^2 = R+1$ and hence to the golden ratio (and its reciprocal).

Comment: Hi, @gammatester can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? =)

Comment: Hi, just did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for part A. Multiply the equation with M:

$$\epsilon_{k+1} = M\epsilon_{k}\epsilon_{k-1}$$
$$\Longrightarrow M\epsilon_{k+1} = (M\epsilon_{k})(M\epsilon_{k-1})$$
$$\Longrightarrow \log\left(M\epsilon_{k+1}\right) = \log\left((M\epsilon_{k})(M\epsilon_{k-1})\right)$$
Apply the functional equation for the $\log$ of a product
$$\Longrightarrow \log\left(M\epsilon_{k+1}\right) = \log(M\epsilon_{k})+\log(M\epsilon_{k-1})$$
and substitute the definition of $y_k$
$$\Longrightarrow y_{k+1} = y_{k}+y_{k-1}$$