# How to show that regula falsi has linear rate of convergence?

Tags: numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence, regula-falsi

How can we prove that regula falsi method  has linear rate of convergence?

I know how to do so for the secant method but I am unable to derive it for regula falsi.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Assume that the function looks locally like $cx(x+d)$, $c,d>0$, and show that the function value at the mid-point is always negative, thus leaving the right point unchanged.

Comment: @LutzL:can you explain it in detail?

Answer (score 2):

Assume first that the function has a root in $x=0$ and looks locally around $x=0$ like $f(x)=cx(x+d)$ with $c,d>0$ and the bracketing interval $[a,b]$ satisfying $-d<a<0<b$.

Now show that the function value at the mid-point
$$
m=\frac{af(b)-bf(a)}{f(b)-f(a)}=\frac{ab·c(b-a)}{c(b-a)(b+a+d)}=\frac{ab}{a+b+d}<0
$$
is always negative (or show $m=a\frac{b}{b+(a+d)}>a>-d$),
$$
f(m)=c·\frac{ab}{a+b+d}·\frac{ab+da+db+d^2}{a+b+d}=c·\frac{ab(a+d)(b+d)}{((a+d)+b)^2}<0,
$$
as $a+d>0$. This means that the midpoint $m$ is always used to replace the left point $a$. For sufficiently small $a$, $$a_+=m\approx\beta a$$ with $\beta=\frac{b}{b+d}$ which establishes the linear convergence.

As $d$ is determined by the curvature of the function $f$, the convergence speed depends only on $b$, the farther $b$ is from $0$, the closer $β$ is to $1$, thus the slower the convergence. This also tells that any measure, no matter how crude, that decreases $b$ will substantially increase the speed of convergence.

---

To translate this to the more general case, compare the quadratic approximation $$cx(x+d)=cdx+cx^2$$ with the quadratic Taylor polynomial $$f(x^*+x)=f(x^*)+f'(x^*)x+\frac12f''(x^*)x^2+o(x^2)$$ in
the root $f(x^*)=0$.

We find $c=2f''(x^*)$ and $cd=f'(x^*)$, which of course only makes sense if both quantities are different from zero. Apply reflections on the $x$ and $y$ axes to get both derivatives and thus both of $c$ and $d$ to be positive.

Comment: can we show the rate of convergence by error equation?

Comment: @LutzL t think we should use approximation $f(x)$ as a straight line (a chord ) [a Linear function of $x$ ],and the difference between Secant and Regula Falsi method is in Regula Falsi method we just check the product of function values is $< 0$.

Comment: @BAYMAX : You do that in the method. However, in analyzing the behaviour of the method your function approximation has to be at least one degree higher.

Comment: @LutzL is it a theorem ? if so kindly tell which one ..can you explain through error method ?

Comment: This is not yet a theorem, more a general explanation for a widely observable behavior of the method. One would have to tighten some screws to make a theorem of it. The general claim would be that if $f(x^*)=0$ and $f'(x^*)\ne0$, $f''(x^*)\ne0$ then stalling, i.e., linear convergence in this pattern will occur at some point.

Answer (score 1):

In [*Comparative Analysis of Convergence of Various
Numerical Methods*](http://compmath-journal.org/dnload/Robin-Kumar-and-Vipan-/CMJV06I06P0290.pdf) by Robin Kumar and Vipan, the authors derive the convergence rate of some common numerical methods for solving equations.

In the specific case of the Regula-Falsi method, the authors assume the function is convex on an interval $]x_0,x_1[$ that contains the root, which implies one of the extreme points remains fixed. Then the linear convergence is derived in a similar way as it was in the secant method.

There are other references to derive the rate of convergence. You may try [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518340/convergence-analysis-of-regula-falsi-method?rq=1) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869871/order-of-convergence-of-false-position-method-is-the-golden-ratio) and their associated references if you want other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple derivation may be done by releasing regula falsi degenerates into fixed-point iteration. Assume $f$ is convex in a neighborhood of the root. Let $b$ be the point which never changes in regula falsi. Let $x_n$ be the points that are updated each iteration. We then have a fixed-point iteration given by:

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{bf(x_n)-x_nf(b)}{f(x_n)-f(b)}=\Phi(x_n)$$

We then have the error given roughly by

$$x-x_{n+1}\simeq\Phi'(x)(x-x_n)$$

which, provided that $\Phi'(x)\in(0,1)$, means linear convergence. With the convexity assumption, one can show that $\Phi'(x)\in(0,1]$ is true, and assuming the root is simple one may further show that $\Phi'(x)\in(0,1)$.