# Convergence Analysis of Regula Falsi method

Tags: numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence, regula-falsi

I was reading about the convergence analysis of the regula falsi method in the book *A friendly introduction to numerical analysis* by B. Bradie.

I got stuck in the last step where $e_n=\lambda e_{n-1}$ and $$\lambda= \frac{l f''(p)}{2f'(p)+l f''(p)}$$ which comes from equation (4). However, I think we should have one more term in the denominator $a_n-p$ or $b_n-p$. Why did the author not consider it? If we consider it, then we won't get $e_n=\lambda e_{n-1}$ as now we also have one $e_{n-1}$ in the denominator.

> **Convergence Analysis**
>
> Does the sequence of approximations generated by the method of false
>   position, $\{p_n\}$ converge to a root $p$? If so, what is the order
>   of convergence? To answer these questions, we need to examine the
>   associated sequence of errors, $\{e_n\}$, where $e_n = p_n - p$. The
>   sequence $\{p_n\}$ converges if and only if $|e_n| \to 0$ as $n \to
>  \infty$ and the order of convergencee is ddetermined by the asymptotic
>   relationship between $|e_n|$ and $|e_{n-1}|$.
>
> The error sequence $\{e_n\}$ is governed by what is known as the
>   *error evolution equation*. To construct the error evolution equation, take the equation for $p_n$ and subtract $p$ from both sides. This
>   yields: $$p_n - p = b_n - p - f(b_n) \frac{b_n - a_n}{f(b_n) -
>  f(a_n)}$$ Next, approximate the function values $f(a_n)$ and $f(b_n)$
>   by the second degree Taylor polynomials $$f(a_n) \approx
>  f'(p)(a_n-p)+\frac{f''(p)}{2}(a_n-p)^2,$$ $$f(b_n) \approx
>  f'(p)(b_n-p)+\frac{f''(p)}{2}(b_n-p)^2$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The removal of one term is due to the fact that one of the bounds will converge to the root while the other will not. Suppose $a\to p$. Then $l=b-p$ and $(b+a-2p)\to(b+p-2p)=(b-p)=l$. On the other hand, $a-p$ is written as $e_{n-1}$, the term $\lambda$ is being multiplied to.

Comment: sir ,can you give some hint regarding how to show that one of the endpoints is staying fixed ? Is it because $f \in C^{2}[a,b]$ ?